# How can I override OnTriggerEnter?

Tags: unity

I am trying to extend Unity's BoxCollider class.  So I am extending it in the editor like such:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(BoxCollider))]
public class MyBoxCollider : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("My Box Collider");
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
    }
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to override OnTriggerEnter, OnCollisionEnter, etc.

How can I override these?  They appear to be declared as private in the base class.

My end goal is that when I add a BoxCollider to a GameObject, it has a label in addition to its normal stuff. Then when BoxCollider's OnTriggerEnter method is called, it prints out what the label says before continuing on about its business. (This is a simplification, but I think it helps clarify my objective.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It looks like you're extending `Editor` instead of `Collider`. `Editor` doesn't have `OnTriggerEnter`, etc to override.

Comment: @Byte56 this overrides BoxCollider. Note the Custom Editor line above the class declaration. (Although I may be misunderstanding...I am new to this.)

Comment: The line above is defining a custom editor for the type `BoxCollider`. It's not overriding a BoxCollider. Maybe you can describe what your end goal is, I'm a bit lost.

Comment: @Byte56 I updated my question

Comment: @Byte56 I now see how my question is unclear :-) took me a second. I'll fix it in the morning